# Getting this error message:- "KDC has no support for encryption type while getting initial credentials"

Tags: centos, kerberos, windows-server-2003, sssd

Trying to connect a Linux machine running CentOS to an MS Windows Active Directory domain ( Server Windows 2003 )

**Version**

Client - Linux

uname -r => 4.18.0-147.5.1.el8_1.x86_64
lsb_release -d => CentOS Linux release 8.1.1911 (Core)

Server
MS Windows 2003

**Command**

KRB5_TRACE=/dev/stdout kinit -V

**Output**

> KRB5_TRACE=/dev/stdout kinit -V dadeniji@LAB.org.

```
Using default cache: 1000
Using principal: dadeniji@LAB.org.
[2448] 1588503907.189313: Getting initial credentials for dadeniji@LAB.org.
[2448] 1588503907.189315: Sending unauthenticated request
[2448] 1588503907.189316: Sending request (224 bytes) to LAB.org.
[2448] 1588503907.189317: Sending DNS URI query for _kerberos.LAB.org.
[2448] 1588503907.189318: No URI records found
[2448] 1588503907.189319: Sending DNS SRV query for _kerberos._udp.LAB.org.
[2448] 1588503907.189320: SRV answer: 0 100 88 "dc01.LAB.org."
[2448] 1588503907.189321: Sending DNS SRV query for _kerberos._tcp.LAB.org.
[2448] 1588503907.189322: SRV answer: 0 100 88 "dc01.LAB.org."
[2448] 1588503907.189323: Resolving hostname dc01.LAB.org.
[2448] 1588503907.189324: Sending initial UDP request to dgram 10.0.4.6:88
[2448] 1588503907.189325: Received answer (104 bytes) from dgram 10.0.4.6:88
[2448] 1588503907.189326: Sending DNS URI query for _kerberos.LAB.org.
[2448] 1588503907.189327: No URI records found
[2448] 1588503907.189328: Sending DNS SRV query for _kerberos-master._udp.LAB.org.
[2448] 1588503907.189329: No SRV records found
[2448] 1588503907.189330: Response was not from master KDC
[2448] 1588503907.189331: Received error from KDC: -1765328370/KDC has no support for encryption type
[2448] 1588503907.189332: Retrying AS request with master KDC
[2448] 1588503907.189333: Getting initial credentials for dadeniji@LAB.org.
[2448] 1588503907.189335: Sending unauthenticated request
[2448] 1588503907.189336: Sending request (224 bytes) to LAB.org. (master)
[2448] 1588503907.189337: Sending DNS URI query for _kerberos.LAB.org.
[2448] 1588503907.189338: No URI records found
[2448] 1588503907.189339: Sending DNS SRV query for _kerberos-master._udp.LAB.org.
[2448] 1588503907.189340: Sending DNS SRV query for _kerberos-master._tcp.LAB.org.
[2448] 1588503907.189341: No SRV records found
kinit: KDC has no support for encryption type while getting initial credentials
```

**Works Around Attempted**

***Specify Encryption Type***

```
    default_tgs_enctypes = rc4-hmac des-cbc-crc des-cbc-md5
    defaukt_tkt_enctypes = rc4-hmac des-cbc-crc des-cbc-md5
    permitted_enctypes = rc4-hmac des-cbc-crc des-cbc-md5
    allow_weak_crypto = true
```

***Active Directory Account Setting***

Set Active Directory Account

1. Use Kerberos DES encryption types for this account

**More here**

https://docs.google.com/document/d/102UCuMB5IkiPb15468EcWN8-h-t6PfRe1rq6Q7x1IOc/edit?usp=sharing

**Summary**
Trying to see if there are clear workarounds to getting latest version of Linux\sssd to hook into an MS Windows 2003 based Active Directory.

Comment: CentoS 8 does not support DES:  https://access.redhat.com/articles/3642912. Note:  CentOS 8 is the same as RHEL 8, but without the Red Hat branding.

Comment: Todd:  - Sorry for my tardiness in responding.  I read the article and you are very right that DES has been completely removed since RHEL version 7.  

But, that rc4-hmac is still supported.

The exact reading is "Disabled in DEFAULT policy, but enabled in LEGACY policy".

To avail my self to legacy mode, I will have to issue this command:-

update-crypto-policies --set LEGACY

Comment: And, rebooted my machine.

Things appear to be working.  Shortly, I will connect to the MS Windows box and review my logs and see if I am able to tell for sure which encryption algorithm is being used.

I was so frustrated yesterday and installed 3rd party applications and got things working.  And, so I am not quite sure at this point if this change is now allowing me to use the original plain implementation.

Meanwhile, thank you so very much, for throwing me a much-needed lifeline.

Comment: Just to be sure - the typo in `defaukt_tkt_enctypes` is not present in your config file, right?

Comment: @Samson Scharfrichter:  You were right.  Big typo on my part.

I in fact had:-

defaukt_tkt_enctypes = rc4-hmac des-cbc-crc des-cbc-md5

Corrected to:-

default_tkt_enctypes = rc4-hmac des-cbc-crc des-cbc-md5